# Parsing Openweathermap request, Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, openweathermap

I'm trying to access openweathermaps API to get the wind speed of a certain location. But it throws me an error every time.

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'speed' of
>   undefined

Here is my location class (or Spot as I have called it):

```
import React, { Component, setState } from 'react'
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import axios from 'axios';

var owmApiKey = 'HIDDEN FROM STACKOVERFLOW';

var myIcon = L.icon({ //SETS UP THE PIN ICON THAT IS USED TO PLOT MARKERS ON THE MAP
    iconUrl: 'https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/678111-map-marker-512.png',
    iconSize: [41,41],
    iconAnchor: [12.5,41],
    popupAnchor: [0, -41]
});

export default class Spot extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super()
        this.state = {
            county_name: props.county_name,
            latitude: props.latitude,
            longitude: props.longitude,
            spot_id: props.spot_id,
            spot_name: props.spot_name,
            wind_speed: 0,
        }
    }

    getWindSpeed = (lon, lat) => {//THE FUNCTION TO POPULATE THE LIST OF SPOTS USING AXIOS
            fetch(`api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${this.state.latitude}&lon=${this.state.longitude}&appid=${owmApiKey}`)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    wind_speed: res.wind.speed
                });
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getWindSpeed();
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <Marker position={[this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude]} icon={myIcon}>
            <Popup>
                {this.state.spot_name + ", " + this.state.county_name + " Wind Speed: " + this.state.wind_speed}
            </Popup>
        </Marker>    
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are getting speed property, in your res.wind
If you don't mind can send the `res` as well which you get from your api.

Comment: after just adding a quick  window.alert(JSON.stringify(res)); it shows me that I actually receive nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's returning an empty body, If i use the API call my browser it shows me the details

Comment: So its not a react issue, check with your api

Comment: I would like to suggest you that, first you should test your api with postman

Comment: I just called the exact same API in postman and it works. So I am very confused

Comment: try to add add host as well infront of api

Comment: Add host? I am not too sure what that means sorry